# CollectionViewSource sort algorithm

Tags: c#, sorting, collectionviewsource

How to change the sort algorithm of CollectionViewSource? In fact, i found that the sort algorithm of CollectionViewSource is not stable. And i want to use a stable algorithm on the CollectionViewSource. How can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to get a stable sorting using a custom Comparer, but it kinda feels like a big hack...

Just like Benjamin suggested, I get the ListCollectionView from the collection and set its CustomSort property with my custom Comparer. The only difference is that I pass the collection to the Comparer when instantiating it.

```
private void Sorting(IEnumerable collection)
{
    var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(collection) as ListCollectionView;

    if (view != null)
    {
        view.CustomSort = new StableComparer(collection);
    }
}
```

Then, in my custom Comparer, I use the collection in the Compare method just to fallback to the items indexes when the comparison returns a zero (they are the same or have the same value).

```
public class StableComparer : IComparer
{
    public IEnumerable Collection { get; set; }

    public StableComparer(IEnumerable collection)
    {
        Collection = collection;
    }

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        IComparable x_Comparable = x as IComparable;
        IComparable y_Comparable = y as IComparable;

        if (x_Comparable != null && y_Comparable != null)
        {
            var comparison = x_Comparable.CompareTo(y_Comparable);

            // A zero value means x and y are equivalent for sorting, and they could
            //  be rearranged by an unstable sorting algorithm
            if (comparison == 0 && Collection != null)
            {
                // IndexOf is an extension method for IEnumerable (not included)
                var x_Index = Collection.IndexOf(x);
                var y_Index = Collection.IndexOf(y);

                // By comparing their indexes in the original collection, we get to
                //  preserve their relative order
                if (x_Index != -1 && y_Index != -1)
                    comparison = x_Index.CompareTo(y_Index);
            }

            return comparison;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

I'm still testing this, so I can't guarantee this would work all the time... One problem would be keeping the Collection property inside the Comparer updated, for instance. Or supporting two sort directions.

But I think the idea is clear, though hacky, as I said.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [how to implement your custom sorting logic](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/441#.U89p1rEZlbU).

In short, set your comparer like this:

```
private void Sort(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    BlogPosts posts = (BlogPosts)(this.Resources["posts"]);
    ListCollectionView lcv = (ListCollectionView)(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(posts));
    lcv.CustomSort = new SortPosts();
}
```

And implement it like this:

```
public class SortPosts : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        (…)
    }
}
```

Comment: this case just set new compare way between two objects. But can it change the stability of sorting algorithm?

Comment: That depends on how you implement your `IComparer`.

Comment: can you give more details? how can i make the stable sorting algorithm with the IComparer? thank you

Comment: You can keep comparing until you find an difference between the two. e.g. you are comparing "abc" and "aac". When you compare the first character, they are the same. To get a stable sorting, keep comparing the next character until you find a difference. So you'd compare with the second character.

Comment: but the stability of sorting algorithm depends on the logic of sorting algorithm